# Adaptive video encoding with alpha channel

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha, webm, widevine

I've created a WebM media file with transparent background in Adobe After Effects. Due to Widevine specs, I have to encode this file to an adaptive format for playing.

With the following command I've successfully created a webm file with DASH:

```
ffmpeg -i example.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -s 200x113 -b:v 250k -keyint_min 150 -g 150 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1 -an -f webm -dash 1 adaptive.webm
```

Unfortunately, the resulting video has lost the alpha channel completely.

Is it possible to encode a video to an adaptive format without losing the alpha channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In this case, you need to use libvpx for decoding as well as encoding, in order to access the alpha channel in the source video. Note the additional codec specifier *before* the input:

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i example.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 250k -keyint_min 150 -g 150 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1 -an -f webm -dash 1 adaptive.webm
```